# Using ruby guard gem to monitor c++ files

Tags: ruby, makefile, guard

I'm using this Guardfile to watch .cpp and .h files and fire off make if anything changes. Works great as long as all files are in the directory the Guardfile is in.

```
guard 'shell' do
    watch(%r{^\w*\.(h|cpp)$}) do
        `make test` 
    end
end
```

I'd like to have the Guardfile in the root directory of my project tree and monitor the .h and .cpp files in each subdirectory. Is it possible to do that by changing the regex, or do I have to have a Guardfile in each subdirectory?

(Not sure why the formatting doesn't go through correctly)

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the following two gems:

```
guard
guard-shell
```

Create a *Guardfile* in the directory where you want to watch the files

```
guard 'shell' do 
  watch(%r{^.+\.(h|hpp|cpp)$}) do 
    `make test`
  end 
end
```

Important that the actual shell command (here: *make test*) has to be wrapped in ` `

Then run:`> guard`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to of this through the regex. Try this:

```
guard 'shell' do 
  watch(%r{^.+\.(h|cpp)$}) do 
    make test 
  end 
end
```

This should match files in any directory below the root directory of your app with the extensions .cpp or .h. If you want to focus to a sub-directory try `^dir/sub/.+\.(h|cpp)$`